# Debugging network communication in iOS background mode

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager, alamofire

I'm working on an iOS app which makes use of the `location` background mode to track [user visits](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLVisit_class/index.html) and then sends some data over to my server. However, I have been experiencing some weird network communication problems. **The only symptom is that not all gathered data gets sent to the server.**

Here is more information on the problem:

1. My server makes logs of everything received. There were no server-side errors and every client request was successfully logged.
2. The client app creates a local notification when the `locationManager:didVisit:` method is called. This notification appears as expected when you arrive and depart at some location. Then, it calls the server over HTTPS and posts another notification, which doesn't appear every time. The whole setup looks like this:

   ```
   // This code is executed from locationManager:didVisit: when the app is in background.
   let myVisit: CLVisit! = ... // the received visit
   self.postLocalNotification("Visit received!", visit: myVisit)

   let task = UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler(nil)
   Alamofire.request(.POST, apiMethod("visit"), parameters: params, encoding: .JSON)
            .responseJSON { (request, response, JSON, error) in
                // This gets executed only some time, wtf?
                self.postLocalNotification("Visit reported!", visit: myVisit)
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(task)
            }
   ```

Therefore, I conclude I'm doing something wrong, yet I don't see what. I have checked [the article on background app execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) and my app seems to comply with it. What else could I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Is your app in registered to support background mode?

Since you receive location updates, your app should qualify to be set to run in background mode.  Set the "Required background mode" in your plist file.

That will let it fully run in the background and you can get rid of the beginBackgroundTask lines.

The beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler methods are typically used to request a little extra time for a current task to be completed provided that your app is in the foreground and it moves to the background in the middle of a task.  To me it sounds like you want to run in full background mode.

With that said, you should still detected that your program is backgrounded and avoid running unneeded cpu intensive tasks to save battery life.

Comment: My app is already registered for the `location` background mode. That should suffice, right? btw, I thought that the beginBackgroundTask is a requirement for any background task regardless of whether the app uses a full background mode, I stand corrected.

Comment: Try just running your app with those background task and let us know how it works.

Comment: will do; is there a effective way of debugging this? it doesn't seem convenient to wait for the next `didVisit` event

Comment: Assuming you can't keep a mac tethered.... write data to a text file and pull it the device when you get back.